# Dev Express Populating XtraGrid.GridControl Using RunWorkerAsync Skin Issue

Tags: vb.net, outlook, interop, devexpress

I have an odd issue where if I populate my XtraGrid.GridControl using RunWorkerAsync the current selected skin does not apply itself to the grid scrollbars [on program load].

If I don't populate the grid Asynchronously the theme is applied to the scroll bars.

More about my code:

I using Outlook interop to collect a list of emails and populate them to simulate an email inbox. I need it to run async else the program snarls up.

I am using:

```
Private WithEvents m_backgroundWorkerInbox As New BackgroundWorker  

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    ' some general settings code + connection to outlook
    m_backgroundWorkerInbox.RunWorkerAsync()

end sub

Private Sub m_backgroundWorkerInbox_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles m_backgroundWorkerInbox.DoWork
    ' do some work
End Sub

Private Sub m_backgroundWorkerInbox_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles m_backgroundWorkerInbox.RunWorkerCompleted
    ' do some work

End Sub
```

If I bypass the async and copy the code out of the async workers and put it in the `New()` the scrollbars collect the correct theme at first program load.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I found:

If you set a skin after the data has loaded into the grid it will apply the skin to the scrollbar. The issue is that you cannot reapply the same skin, you need to switch out to do it.

A good but hacky solution could be to populate the grid with 20 rows of duff data from a different data source then when tbe data is loaded empty and repopulate the grid.